# callback with void pointer argument produce warning

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, void-pointers

I have the following code:

```
/* callback taking a pointer to a "generic" msg as argument */
typedef void (*Callback_t)(void *msg);

/* initialize callback pointer */
Callback_t const Callback[] =
{
  ProcessMsgAction0,  /**< 0: MSGID_ACTION_0 */
  ProcessMsgAction1,  /**< 1: MSGID_ACTION_1 */
  /* ... */
};

/* Call the callback according to msgid */
msg = GetMessage();
Callback[msg->id](msg);

/* implement callback for each message id */
void ProcessMsgAction0(action0_t *msg) { /* ... */ }
void ProcessMsgAction1(action1_t *msg) { /* ... */ }
```

I though void* was considered as generic pointer. So whatever address i give it wont produce a warning but on the case above `action0_t*` is different of `void*` so it produce the following warning: `initialization from incompatible pointer type`

If I want to suppress the warning, is my only solution to change ProcessMsgAction argument to void* ?

compile option used: -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I though void* was considered as generic pointer
```

This is true, but the notion does not extend to matching parameters in function types.

A simple typecast to `Callback_t` works however, [see this functional example on ideone.](http://ideone.com/rt5cY8)

Comment: Should be noted, that this is undefined (depending on what OP really does with the pointer, but it does look like it eventually will be undefined). (And also noted, that it works on most machines, and I can't really think of a way a compiler could make use of this UB etc.) And perhaps replace the `reinterpret_cast` by a C-style pointer cast (this is a C question, not C++).

Comment: [A function pointer cast is a bug waiting to happen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx).  Don't do it.  It's much better to declare your function as `void ProcessMsgAction0(void *msg) {}` and internally cast from `void*` to `action0_t*`.

Comment: I would like to avoid it, but i have no other choice than to use it. Each message have a different structure size but it use the same way.